# OpenMDAO 1.2.0 implicit component

Tags: openmdao

I new to OpenMDAO and I'm still learning how to formulate the problems.
For a simple example, let's say I have 3 input variables with the given bounds:

```
1 <= x <= 10
0 <= y <= 10
1 <= z <= 10
```

and I have 4 outputs, defined as:

```
f1 = x * y
f2 = 2 * z
g1 = x + y - 1
g2 = z
```

my goal is to minimize f1 * g1, but enforce the constraint f1 = f2 and g1 = g2.  For example, one solution is x=3, y=4, z=6 (no idea if this is optimal).

For this simple problem, you can probably just feed the output equality constraints to the driver.  However, for my actual problem it's hard to find an initial starting point that satisfy all the constraints, and as the result the optimizer failed to do anything.  I figure maybe I could define y and z as states in an implicit component and have a nonlinear solver figure out the right values of y and z given x, then feed x to the optimization driver.

Is this a possible approach?  If so, how will the implicit component look like in this case?  I looked at the Sellar problem tutorial but I wasn't able to translate it to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an implicit component if you want. In that case, you would define an `apply_linear` method in your component. That is done with the sellar problem [here](http://openmdao.readthedocs.org/en/1.2.0/usr-guide/tutorials/sellar.html#sellar-with-an-implicit-component).

In your case since you have a 2 equation set of residuals which are both dependent on the state variables, I suggest you create a single array state variable of length 2, call it `foo` (I used a new variable to avoid any confusion, but name it whatever you want!). Then you will define two residuals, one for each element of the residual array of the new state variable.

Something like:

```
resids['foo'][0] = params['x'] * unknowns['foo'][0] - 2 * unknowns['foo'][1]
resids['foo'][1] = params['x'] + unknowns['foo'][0] - 1 - unknowns['foo'][1]
```

If you wanted to keep the state variable names separate you could, and it will still work. You'll just have to arbitrarily assign one residual equation to one variable and one to the other.

Then the only thing left is to add a non linear solver to the group containing your implicit component and it should work. If you choose to use a newton solver, you'll either need to set `fd_options['force_fd'] = True` or define derivatives of your residuals wrt all params and state variables.

Comment: Thanks for the help, some more questions:

1. is "foo" supposed to be "s"? If not, why are we not using `unknowns['foo'][1]` and `unknowns['s'][0]`?

2. I'm always confused about the names of residuals; is residual for a state variable supposed to have the same name as that variable?  Does that imply they're somehow the same variable?  If so, is derivative of a residual wrt the state with the same name always 1?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I edited my answer to be correct. It should be 'foo' everywhere.